# Request a Modal To a Browser to select certificate

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'm looking for days on the internet a method to get certificates installed in the browser via Javascript (the same way it works on windows). Or a way to get the certificates installed in linux (using java). I've heard of a lib called WebCrypto that all browsers have, but the method I need does not have the most support in today's browsers.

A need to request a modal in browser to select one personal certificate installed on it . I need a trigger in Javascript to do this. OR code in Java to get a cert installed in linux OS.

Example :

https://www.startssl.com/Account

Click in Client Certificate Login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but what you are asking is not achievable (in terms of your needs).

At first, certificate selection UI dialog MAY or MAY NOT appear only when server requests client certificate for mutual authentication.

Two problems here:

1. Web browser MAY decide to not pop-up the dialog. This may happen when only one client certificate is installed in the user certificate store. In other words, it is up to browser (or its configuration) to show or not to show the certificate selection dialog.
2. Even if it shown, it is displayed on client side and is not part of DOM, as the result, you cannot have any interactions with certificate selection dialog from JavaScript.

(1) cannot be solved by server configuration, because it is client behvaiour you have no control over.

(2) can be solved by calling web-enabled client interfaces (similar to ActiveX controls in Internet Explorer), but there must be such support and client must agree to allow such calls. Unfortunately, there is no universal built-in framework that would work even on major browsers and operating systems. The closest is Java, but it is not built-in, client must have installed Java engine.